# Inserting PHP class properties as SQL query variables within the PHP class

Tags: php, sql, oop, pdo, prepared-statement

I am a serious newbie trying to update some mysqli LAMP code to PDO/OOP. I am sure my new code is inefficient. I am just using this project as a learning experience.

I am trying to pass a few PHP class properties to a MySQL query that is within a method within that same PHP class. This would accomplish a basic insert into a single mysql table. I have tried this using both PDO prepared statements and the basic PDO::query method.

When i attempt the insert using the prepared statements version of my class (code below) i get a "Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object" error on line 27 (the first bindParam line).

```
<?php
class weightInfoInsert
{

// properties
private $date;
private $weight;
private $note;
private $dbc;
private $insertQueryWithNote;
private $sth;

// methods
public function __construct($date, $weight, $note, $dbc)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->weight = $weight;
        $this->note = $note;
        $this->dbc = $dbc;
    }   

public function insertWeightWithNote()
    {
        $insertQueryWithNote = ' INSERT INTO weight (weight_date,weight,weight_note) VALUES ( :date, :weight, :note ) ';

        $sth = $this->dbc->prepare($insertQueryWithNote);
            $sth->bindParam(':date', $this->date, PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);
            $sth->bindParam(':weight', $this->weight, PDO::PARAM_STR, 5);
            $sth->bindParam(':note', $this->note, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $this->sth->execute();
    }
}
```

When i attempt the insert using the PDO::query() method (code below), i get "syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)" on line 23 (the query statement line).

```
<?php
class weightInfoInsert
{

// properties
private $date;
private $weight;
private $note;
private $dbc;
private $insertQueryWithNote;

// methods
public function __construct($date, $weight, $note, $dbc)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->weight = $weight;
        $this->note = $note;
        $this->dbc = $dbc;
    }   

public function insertWeight()
    {
        $insertQueryWithNote = ' INSERT INTO weight (weight_date,weight) VALUES ('$this->date','$this->weight','$this-note') ';
        $this->dbc->query($insertQueryWithNote);

    }

}
```

While i will probably use the prepared statements method, i would ideally like to know where i went wrong on both methods. Thank you.

Comment: As you can see from your example, it shows you that your quotes are the problem on the second class: `$insertQueryWithNote = "INSERT INTO weight (weight_date,weight) VALUES ('$this->date','$this->weight','$this-note')";` Need to be double quotes, not single

Comment: That worked just fine. Thanks for pointing that out. I am a bit confused as i have other queries that are enclosed in single quotes that work perfectly. They do not however contain any variables, so perhaps that is what makes the difference. Guess i need to read up on the PHP best practices for single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, there were syntax problems with `'` and `$this-note` should be `$this->note`

```
$insertQueryWithNote = "INSERT INTO weight (weight_date,weight) VALUES ('$this->date','$this->weight','$this->note')";
```

Comment: Thanks, as i commented above, the double quotes made everything fall into place (once i fixed the > typo).